# duplicate views in view hierarchy testing using espresso with react native

Tags: android, react-native, automated-tests, android-espresso

I'm trying to run tests I've created in espresso to test a react native app.  I'm trying to target particular buttons to be clicked using AccessibilityLabels, which are successfully appearing as content-descriptions and are being targeted by espresso.  The problem is, I'm getting errors because espresso thinks they are duplicate views, however, they only appear in my react native code once.  I am using a common button component in react native.  Any ideas whats causing this?

The error is below:  id 47 and 76 are the duplicated views

```
    android.support.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException: '(with content description: is "LOG IN" and is displayed on the screen to the user)' matches multiple views in the hierarchy.
Problem views are marked with '****MATCHES****' below.

View Hierarchy:
+>DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1920, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=3}
|
+->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1794, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+-->ViewStub{id=16909295, res-name=action_mode_bar_stub, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+-->FrameLayout{id=16908290, res-name=content, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1731, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=63.0, child-count=1}
|
+--->ReactRootView{id=1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1731, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+---->ReactViewGroup{id=10, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1731, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+----->ReactViewGroup{id=14, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1731, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+------>ReactViewGroup{id=15, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1731, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+------->ReactViewGroup{id=18, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1731, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+-------->ReactViewGroup{id=19, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1731, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+--------->ReactImageView{id=22, visibility=VISIBLE, width=788, height=263, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=146.0, y=734.0}
|
+------->ReactViewGroup{id=24, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1731, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+-------->ReactViewGroup{id=25, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1731, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+--------->ReactViewGroup{id=28, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1731, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+---------->ReactViewGroup{id=32, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1731, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=8}
|
+----------->ReactImageView{id=35, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=447, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=-79.0}
|
+----------->ReactViewGroup{id=36, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=-158.0, child-count=0}
|
+----------->ReactViewGroup{id=37, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=157, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=-158.0, child-count=0}
|
+----------->ReactImageView{id=40, visibility=VISIBLE, width=788, height=262, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=146.0, y=457.0}
|
+----------->ReactTextView{id=43, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1027, height=155, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=26.0, y=853.0, text=The easy way to organise parties, events, share pictures and memories with friends, family and groups., input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+----------->ReactViewGroup{id=47, desc=LOG IN, visibility=VISIBLE, width=975, height=174, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=53.0, y=1148.0, child-count=1} ****MATCHES****
|
+------------>ReactTextView{id=48, visibility=VISIBLE, width=150, height=65, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=413.0, y=54.0, text=LOG IN, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+----------->ReactTextView{id=52, visibility=VISIBLE, width=56, height=57, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=512.0, y=1355.0, text=OR, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+----------->ReactViewGroup{id=54, desc=SIGN UP, visibility=VISIBLE, width=975, height=173, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=53.0, y=1453.0, child-count=1}
|
+------------>ReactTextView{id=55, visibility=VISIBLE, width=182, height=65, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=397.0, y=54.0, text=SIGN UP, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+--------->ReactViewGroup{id=57, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1731, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+---------->ReactViewGroup{id=60, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1731, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=8}
|
+----------->ReactImageView{id=64, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=447, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=-79.0}
|
+----------->ReactViewGroup{id=65, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=-158.0, child-count=0}
|
+----------->ReactViewGroup{id=66, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=157, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=-158.0, child-count=0}
|
+----------->ReactImageView{id=69, visibility=VISIBLE, width=788, height=262, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=146.0, y=457.0}
|
+----------->ReactTextView{id=72, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1027, height=155, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=26.0, y=853.0, text=The easy way to organise parties, events, share pictures and memories with friends, family and groups., input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|

// this is the same as id=47
+----------->ReactViewGroup{id=76, desc=LOG IN, visibility=VISIBLE, width=975, height=174, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=53.0, y=1148.0, child-count=1} ****MATCHES****
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use function

```
ViewMatchers.withId(47)
```

to get your view